# Svg icon remove mask and use tags

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am getting svgs icons from my designer that looks like the following:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 49 (51002) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>icons/Search</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <path d="M19.9540595,19.3616366 L15.8890991,15.2679046 C18.3035819,12.5133747 18.0987254,8.33903567 15.4261496,5.83443006 C12.7535738,3.32982445 8.57707245,3.39817204 5.98778844,5.98888691 C3.39850443,8.57960179 3.33019459,12.7584111 5.8334169,15.4324638 C8.33663921,18.1065165 12.5086727,18.3114862 15.2616813,15.8956692 L19.3619892,19.9540341 C19.5318715,20.0382483 19.7365147,20.0046375 19.8705748,19.8705033 C20.0046349,19.7363691 20.0382272,19.5316129 19.9540595,19.3616366 Z M10.7813881,16.7091105 C7.53099588,16.7091105 4.8960324,14.0726909 4.8960324,10.8205025 C4.8960324,7.56831416 7.53099588,4.93189457 10.7813881,4.93189457 C14.0317802,4.93189457 16.6667437,7.56831416 16.6667437,10.8205025 C16.6571029,14.0520297 14.0464342,16.6720327 10.8167355,16.691427 L10.7813881,16.7091105 Z" id="path-1"/>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" transform="translate(-704.000000, -382.000000)">
            <g id="icons/Search" transform="translate(700.000000, 378.000000)">
                <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                </mask>
                <use id="Search" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                <g id="mixin/primary-300" mask="url(#mask-2)" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <g transform="translate(-3.000000, -3.000000)" id="Rectangle-6">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" rx="2"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The problem is that the id's that used by the `use` and `mask` tags are not unique and can be the same in another SVG that I get.

There is a way to flat this or something? I have no knowledge in the field so I could use your help. (or automatic tool)

Comment: Ask your designer to make sure, the IDs are unique (maybe based on the source image ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a deduping ids function.

**Note:** It's rather aggressive, in the sense that it will completely remove any bound events on internal elements of `<svg>`s that need `id` replacement, because I'm treating their `outerHTML` as a string, replacing `id`s when needed and replacing the entire `outerHTML` of the `<svg>` with the resulting string. Having events bound on `<svg>` internal tags would be unusual and quite rare, but not impossible, hence my warning. I was also a tad lazy and wrote it in jQuery, as it would have taken more in vanilla, at least for me.

```js
function dedupeIDs() {
  let allSVGs = $('svg'),
    allIDs = [];
  allSVGs.each((i, e) => {
    let outer = e.outerHTML;
    $('[id]', e).each((o, k) => {
      let unique = k.id;
      if (allIDs.indexOf(k.id) > -1) {
        unique = createUniqueId(k.id, allIDs);
        outer = outer.replace('"#' + k.id + '"', '"#' + unique + '"')
          .replace('"' + k.id + '"', '"' + unique + '"');
      }
      allIDs.push(unique);
    })
    if (e.outerHTML !== outer) {
      e.outerHTML = outer;
    };
  })

  function createUniqueId(id, ids) {
    let i = 0;
    while (++i && ids.indexOf(id.replace(/\d+/g, '') + i) > -1);
    return id.replace(/\d+/g, '') + i;
  }
}
$(window).load(dedupeIDs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 49 (51002) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>icons/Search</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <path d="M19.9540595,19.3616366 L15.8890991,15.2679046 C18.3035819,12.5133747 18.0987254,8.33903567 15.4261496,5.83443006 C12.7535738,3.32982445 8.57707245,3.39817204 5.98778844,5.98888691 C3.39850443,8.57960179 3.33019459,12.7584111 5.8334169,15.4324638 C8.33663921,18.1065165 12.5086727,18.3114862 15.2616813,15.8956692 L19.3619892,19.9540341 C19.5318715,20.0382483 19.7365147,20.0046375 19.8705748,19.8705033 C20.0046349,19.7363691 20.0382272,19.5316129 19.9540595,19.3616366 Z M10.7813881,16.7091105 C7.53099588,16.7091105 4.8960324,14.0726909 4.8960324,10.8205025 C4.8960324,7.56831416 7.53099588,4.93189457 10.7813881,4.93189457 C14.0317802,4.93189457 16.6667437,7.56831416 16.6667437,10.8205025 C16.6571029,14.0520297 14.0464342,16.6720327 10.8167355,16.691427 L10.7813881,16.7091105 Z" id="path-1"/>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" transform="translate(-704.000000, -382.000000)">
            <g id="icons/Search" transform="translate(700.000000, 378.000000)">
                <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                </mask>
                <use id="Search" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                <g id="mixin/primary-300" mask="url(#mask-2)" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <g transform="translate(-3.000000, -3.000000)" id="Rectangle-6">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" rx="2"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 49 (51002) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>icons/Search</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <path d="M19.9540595,19.3616366 L15.8890991,15.2679046 C18.3035819,12.5133747 18.0987254,8.33903567 15.4261496,5.83443006 C12.7535738,3.32982445 8.57707245,3.39817204 5.98778844,5.98888691 C3.39850443,8.57960179 3.33019459,12.7584111 5.8334169,15.4324638 C8.33663921,18.1065165 12.5086727,18.3114862 15.2616813,15.8956692 L19.3619892,19.9540341 C19.5318715,20.0382483 19.7365147,20.0046375 19.8705748,19.8705033 C20.0046349,19.7363691 20.0382272,19.5316129 19.9540595,19.3616366 Z M10.7813881,16.7091105 C7.53099588,16.7091105 4.8960324,14.0726909 4.8960324,10.8205025 C4.8960324,7.56831416 7.53099588,4.93189457 10.7813881,4.93189457 C14.0317802,4.93189457 16.6667437,7.56831416 16.6667437,10.8205025 C16.6571029,14.0520297 14.0464342,16.6720327 10.8167355,16.691427 L10.7813881,16.7091105 Z" id="path-1"/>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" transform="translate(-704.000000, -382.000000)">
            <g id="icons/Search" transform="translate(700.000000, 378.000000)">
                <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                </mask>
                <use id="Search" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                <g id="mixin/primary-300" mask="url(#mask-2)" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <g transform="translate(-3.000000, -3.000000)" id="Rectangle-6">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" rx="2"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 49 (51002) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>icons/Search</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <path d="M19.9540595,19.3616366 L15.8890991,15.2679046 C18.3035819,12.5133747 18.0987254,8.33903567 15.4261496,5.83443006 C12.7535738,3.32982445 8.57707245,3.39817204 5.98778844,5.98888691 C3.39850443,8.57960179 3.33019459,12.7584111 5.8334169,15.4324638 C8.33663921,18.1065165 12.5086727,18.3114862 15.2616813,15.8956692 L19.3619892,19.9540341 C19.5318715,20.0382483 19.7365147,20.0046375 19.8705748,19.8705033 C20.0046349,19.7363691 20.0382272,19.5316129 19.9540595,19.3616366 Z M10.7813881,16.7091105 C7.53099588,16.7091105 4.8960324,14.0726909 4.8960324,10.8205025 C4.8960324,7.56831416 7.53099588,4.93189457 10.7813881,4.93189457 C14.0317802,4.93189457 16.6667437,7.56831416 16.6667437,10.8205025 C16.6571029,14.0520297 14.0464342,16.6720327 10.8167355,16.691427 L10.7813881,16.7091105 Z" id="path-1"/>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" transform="translate(-704.000000, -382.000000)">
            <g id="icons/Search" transform="translate(700.000000, 378.000000)">
                <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                </mask>
                <use id="Search" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                <g id="mixin/primary-300" mask="url(#mask-2)" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <g transform="translate(-3.000000, -3.000000)" id="Rectangle-6">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" rx="2"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 49 (51002) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>icons/Search</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <path d="M19.9540595,19.3616366 L15.8890991,15.2679046 C18.3035819,12.5133747 18.0987254,8.33903567 15.4261496,5.83443006 C12.7535738,3.32982445 8.57707245,3.39817204 5.98778844,5.98888691 C3.39850443,8.57960179 3.33019459,12.7584111 5.8334169,15.4324638 C8.33663921,18.1065165 12.5086727,18.3114862 15.2616813,15.8956692 L19.3619892,19.9540341 C19.5318715,20.0382483 19.7365147,20.0046375 19.8705748,19.8705033 C20.0046349,19.7363691 20.0382272,19.5316129 19.9540595,19.3616366 Z M10.7813881,16.7091105 C7.53099588,16.7091105 4.8960324,14.0726909 4.8960324,10.8205025 C4.8960324,7.56831416 7.53099588,4.93189457 10.7813881,4.93189457 C14.0317802,4.93189457 16.6667437,7.56831416 16.6667437,10.8205025 C16.6571029,14.0520297 14.0464342,16.6720327 10.8167355,16.691427 L10.7813881,16.7091105 Z" id="path-1"/>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" transform="translate(-704.000000, -382.000000)">
            <g id="icons/Search" transform="translate(700.000000, 378.000000)">
                <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                </mask>
                <use id="Search" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                <g id="mixin/primary-300" mask="url(#mask-2)" fill="#9CA0A0" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <g transform="translate(-3.000000, -3.000000)" id="Rectangle-6">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" rx="2"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

---

**Personal and subjective note**: I meant it more like a proof of concept, I personally wouldn't use it in a production environment. If I had to, i'd rather have the code run only once and manually place the result of each `<svg>` from the page source code inside the `<svg>`s in the source, so I'd have unique `id`s from that point on without needing to run the dedupe function.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the npm package I made called [svgood](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgood). It removes *defs* and *g* (which tend to harbour the *mask*s) elements and floats the *path* element to the top level of the *svg*. After doing this you can apply styles and transforms directly to the svg yourself which tends to be a lot easier and gives you more control than when working around masks. I have some plans for making it more useful but let me know if I can add something that would make it better for your use case.